# How to simply print out a csv file?

Tags: r, powerbi

I'm new to R language, which I'd like to use to enhance Power BI possibilities at some point in the future. For now, I want to print a simple result. What I'm doing wrong in the syntax as follows?

```
`dataset` = read.csv('C:/Users/sjirak/REditorWrapper_0f826ac1-9243-4b4e-a2cd-06da25fc8447/input_df_e3c98b52-de4c-4db4-b2da-f45a313ebdcf.csv', check.names = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8", blank.lines.skip = FALSE);

dataset
```

returns

> > dataset Error: object 'dataset' not found
> >     `dataset` = read.csv('C:/Users/sjirak/REditorWrapper_ee2c9de8-6c73-452a-8b2c-9a60ae163bc8/input_df_ae7939de-4a54-42bb-8705-329849d52ff0.csv', check.names = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8", blank.lines.skip = FALSE);

The CSV file is `1x1`, it has only one value (with a header).

Comment: `dataset` should not be in backticks. I.e. `dataset = read.csv('C:/Users/sjirak/REditorWrapper_0f826ac1-9243-4b4e-a2cd-06da25fc8447/input_df_e3c98b52-de4c-4db4-b2da-f45a313ebdcf.csv', check.names = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8", blank.lines.skip = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing the R code in Power BI, it's much easier to import the CSV into Power BI and then create the visual that you want in Power BI by clicking the R script editor in the Visualisations pane and then dragging and dropping all relevant data columns into that visualisation.

Power BI will then create a dataframe for you (called `dataset`) using the columns that you provided, and you can use this as normal (make note of the change of names, and beware of spacing in your column names)!

Unfortunately Power BI doesn't have any R capabilities other than creating visuals.. it cannot give you the structure of your data set nor show you summary statistics in a matrix, for example. So depending on what kind of result you wanted to print, I would say to find out another way using Power BI or use R in an R IDE ;)